# Problem with user created function to set the upper and lower values from 2 columns in data frame

Tags: r, function, if-statement

I'm trying to create a user created function to set the upper and lower values from 2 columns in data frame, but it doesn't work.

I'm using the `mtcars` data. I want to create a data frame from the function using the variables `gear` and `carb`. The function puts in the `gear`, `carb`, and `mtcars` as arguments. I want to the function to create a data frame in an object called `mtcars_post_function_dataset` that has the variables `gear` and `carb` such that `gear` has the smaller of the 2 variable values and `carb` has the larger of the 2 variable values. In addition, I want it to create 2 variables called `gear_pre_storage` and `carb_pre_storage` which has the original values of `gear` and `carb` from the original `mtcars` data frame.

When I tried to make this function, called `function_set_upper_and_lower_range_values`, and I try to run it with the data of interest, I get the follow output (which is not the desired result):

```
mtcars_post_function_dataset <- 
  function_set_upper_and_lower_range_values(gear, carb, mtcars)
> Error in as.name(lower_value_post) : object 'lower_value_post' not found
```

I'm not sure what to do. Please advise. Thanks ahead of time for any help.

---

---

Here is the code I used for the function:

```
# creates function_set_upper_and_lower_range_values
# ---- NOTE: creates function
function_set_upper_and_lower_range_values <- 
  # ---- NOTE: enter in 2 variables and dataset, function will set data so that lower_value >= upper_value for a given pair of values in 2 columns
  # ---- NOTE: important for confidence interval / credible interval tests
  # ---- NOTE: lower_value == lower value in range being evaluated
  # ---- NOTE: upper_value == lower value in range being evaluated
  # ---- NOTE: object to put function return should be data frame object
  # ---- NOTE: function_range_check_specific == function name
  function(lower_value, upper_value, dataset_name)
  {
    # ---- NOTE: turns function inputs into strings
    lower_value_colmn <- deparse(substitute(lower_value))
    upper_value_colmn <- deparse(substitute(upper_value))
    nm1 <- deparse(substitute(dataset_name))
    # ---- NOTE: # turns dataset_name into data frame
    set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_A <- 
      data.frame(
        dataset_name
      )
    # ---- NOTE: adds column used for merging, and then turns data into data frame
    set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_A <- tibble::rowid_to_column(set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_A, "merging_column")
    # ---- NOTE: turns data into data frame
    set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_A <- data.frame(set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_A)
    # ---- NOTE: selects variables of interest
    set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_B <- 
      set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_A %>% 
      select(
        lower_value_colmn, 
        upper_value_colmn, 
        merging_column
      )
    # ---- NOTE: turns object into data frame
    set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_B <- 
      data.frame(set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_B)
    # ---- NOTE: # transforms values of interest into numeric form
    set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_B$lower_value_pre <- as.numeric(as.character(set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_B[[lower_value_colmn]]))
    set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_B$upper_value_pre <- as.numeric(as.character(set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_B[[upper_value_colmn]]))
    # ---- NOTE: # sets data so lower_value_pre <= upper_value_pre
    # ---- NOTE: ## creates storage variables
    set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_B$upper_value_pre_storage <- set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_B$upper_value_pre
    set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_B$lower_value_pre_storage <- set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_B$lower_value_pre
    # ---- NOTE: ## creates upper_value_colmn
    set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_B$upper_value_post <- 
      ifelse(((set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_B$upper_value_pre_storage) > (set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_B$lower_value_pre_storage)), set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_B$upper_value_pre_storage,
             ifelse(((set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_B$upper_value_pre_storage) < (set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_B$lower_value_pre_storage)), set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_B$lower_value_pre_storage,
                    ifelse(((set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_B$upper_value_pre_storage) == (set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_B$lower_value_pre_storage)), set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_B$upper_value_pre_storage,
                           NA
                    )))
    # ---- NOTE: ## creates lower_value_post
    set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_B$lower_value_post <- 
      ifelse(((set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_B$upper_value_pre_storage) > (set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_B$lower_value_pre_storage)), set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_B$lower_value_pre_storage,
             ifelse(((set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_B$upper_value_pre_storage) < (set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_B$lower_value_pre_storage)), set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_B$upper_value_pre_storage,
                    ifelse(((set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_B$upper_value_pre_storage) == (set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_B$lower_value_pre_storage)), set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_B$lower_value_pre_storage,
                           NA
                    )))
    # ---- NOTE: creates set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_C to be used to combine variables of interest to main dataset
    set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_C <- data.frame(set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_A)
    # ---- NOTE: drops specific columns
    set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_C <- 
      dplyr::select(set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_C, -c(lower_value_colmn, upper_value_colmn))
    # ---- NOTE: selects specific data from set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_B for combining dataset
    set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_D <- 
      merge(set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_C, 
            set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_B, 
            by.x = "merging_column", 
            by.y = "merging_column", 
            all.x = TRUE,
            all.y = FALSE,
            no.dups = TRUE)
    # ---- NOTE: turns object into data frame
    set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_D <- data.frame(set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_D)
    # ---- NOTE: changes colnames
    names(set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_D)[as.name(lower_value_post)] <- lower_value_colmn
    names(set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_D)[as.name(upper_value_post)] <- upper_value_colmn
    names(set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_D)[as.name(lower_value_pre_storage)] <- paste(lower_value_colmn, "pre_storage", sep = "_")
    names(set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_D)[as.name(upper_value_pre_storage)] <- paste(upper_value_colmn, "pre_storage", sep = "_")
    # ---- NOTE: returns proper variable
    return(set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_D)
  }
```

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. If I’m successful at cutting the wording down I’ll post an update edit.

Comment: I looked over the materials, and it seemed to work. But when I tried to apply it to other data, it didn't work for me. I think that this failure is due to my less than ideal abilities at using R. I do appreciate the efforts that you made, and I will respond accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the function, the lines at the end are the problematic i.e. `as.name` is trying to convert an object that doesn't exist in the global env i.e `lower_value_post`, `upper_value_post` are column names in that `set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_D` data.frame object.

```
names(set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_D)[as.name(lower_value_post)] <- lower_value_colmn
names(set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_D)[as.name(upper_value_post)] <- upper_value_colmn
names(set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_D)[as.name(lower_value_pre_storage)] <- paste(lower_value_colmn, "pre_storage", sep = "_")
names(set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_D)[as.name(upper_value_pre_storage)] <- paste(upper_value_colmn, "pre_storage", sep = "_")
```

---

As the OP wanted to rename those specific columns, in `base R` an option would to be match the column name with that vector of column names to get the position index of column.

```
 i1 <- match(c("lower_value_post", "upper_value_post", "lower_value_pre_storage", "upper_value_pre_storage"), names(set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_D))
```

and use that index to extract those column names and assign (`<-`) with new vector of column names in that order

```
 names(set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_D)[i1] <-
     
       c(lower_value_colmn, upper_value_colmn, paste0(c(lower_value_colmn, upper_value_colmn), "_pre_storage"))
```

-full function with changes made

```
function_set_upper_and_lower_range_values <- 
  # ---- NOTE: enter in 2 variables and dataset, function will set data so that lower_value >= upper_value for a given pair of values in 2 columns
  # ---- NOTE: important for confidence interval / credible interval tests
  # ---- NOTE: lower_value == lower value in range being evaluated
  # ---- NOTE: upper_value == lower value in range being evaluated
  # ---- NOTE: object to put function return should be data frame object
  # ---- NOTE: function_range_check_specific == function name
  function(lower_value, upper_value, dataset_name)
  {
    # ---- NOTE: turns function inputs into strings
    lower_value_colmn <- deparse(substitute(lower_value))
    upper_value_colmn <- deparse(substitute(upper_value))
    nm1 <- deparse(substitute(dataset_name))
    # ---- NOTE: # turns dataset_name into data frame
    set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_A <- 
      data.frame(
        dataset_name
      )
    # ---- NOTE: adds column used for merging, and then turns data into data frame
    set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_A <- tibble::rowid_to_column(set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_A, "merging_column")
    # ---- NOTE: turns data into data frame
    set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_A <- data.frame(set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_A)
    # ---- NOTE: selects variables of interest
    set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_B <- 
      set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_A %>% 
      select(
        lower_value_colmn, 
        upper_value_colmn, 
        merging_column
      )
    # ---- NOTE: turns object into data frame
    set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_B <- 
      data.frame(set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_B)
    # ---- NOTE: # transforms values of interest into numeric form
    set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_B$lower_value_pre <- as.numeric(as.character(set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_B[[lower_value_colmn]]))
    set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_B$upper_value_pre <- as.numeric(as.character(set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_B[[upper_value_colmn]]))
    # ---- NOTE: # sets data so lower_value_pre <= upper_value_pre
    # ---- NOTE: ## creates storage variables
    set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_B$upper_value_pre_storage <- set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_B$upper_value_pre
    set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_B$lower_value_pre_storage <- set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_B$lower_value_pre
    # ---- NOTE: ## creates upper_value_colmn
    set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_B$upper_value_post <- 
      ifelse(((set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_B$upper_value_pre_storage) > (set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_B$lower_value_pre_storage)), set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_B$upper_value_pre_storage,
             ifelse(((set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_B$upper_value_pre_storage) < (set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_B$lower_value_pre_storage)), set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_B$lower_value_pre_storage,
                    ifelse(((set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_B$upper_value_pre_storage) == (set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_B$lower_value_pre_storage)), set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_B$upper_value_pre_storage,
                           NA
                    )))
    # ---- NOTE: ## creates lower_value_post
    set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_B$lower_value_post <- 
      ifelse(((set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_B$upper_value_pre_storage) > (set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_B$lower_value_pre_storage)), set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_B$lower_value_pre_storage,
             ifelse(((set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_B$upper_value_pre_storage) < (set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_B$lower_value_pre_storage)), set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_B$upper_value_pre_storage,
                    ifelse(((set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_B$upper_value_pre_storage) == (set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_B$lower_value_pre_storage)), set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_B$lower_value_pre_storage,
                           NA
                    )))
    # ---- NOTE: creates set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_C to be used to combine variables of interest to main dataset
    set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_C <- data.frame(set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_A)
    # ---- NOTE: drops specific columns
    set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_C <- 
      dplyr::select(set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_C, -c(lower_value_colmn, upper_value_colmn))
    # ---- NOTE: selects specific data from set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_B for combining dataset
    set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_D <- 
      merge(set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_C, 
            set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_B, 
            by.x = "merging_column", 
            by.y = "merging_column", 
            all.x = TRUE,
            all.y = FALSE,
            no.dups = TRUE)
    # ---- NOTE: turns object into data frame
    set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_D <- data.frame(set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_D)
    # ---- NOTE: changes colnames
    i1 <- match(c("lower_value_post", "upper_value_post", "lower_value_pre_storage", "upper_value_pre_storage"), names(set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_D))
    names(set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_D)[i1] <-
     
           c(lower_value_colmn, upper_value_colmn, paste0(c(lower_value_colmn, upper_value_colmn), "_pre_storage"))
    
    # ---- NOTE: returns proper variable
    return(set_upper_and_lower_range_values_construction_funct_object_D)
  }
```

-testing

```
function_set_upper_and_lower_range_values(gear, carb, mtcars)
   merging_column  mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb lower_value_pre upper_value_pre carb_pre_storage gear_pre_storage carb
1               1 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4               4               4                4                4    4
2               2 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4               4               4                4                4    4
3               3 22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1               4               1                1                4    4
4               4 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1               3               1                1                3    3
5               5 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2               3               2                2                3    3
6               6 18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1               3               1                1                3    3
7               7 14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4               3               4                4                3    4
8               8 24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2               4               2                2                4    4
9               9 22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2               4               2                2                4    4
10             10 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4               4               4                4                4    4
11             11 17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4               4               4                4                4    4
12             12 16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3               3               3                3                3    3
13             13 17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3               3               3                3                3    3
14             14 15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3               3               3                3                3    3
15             15 10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4               3               4                4                3    4
16             16 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4               3               4                4                3    4
17             17 14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4               3               4                4                3    4
18             18 32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1               4               1                1                4    4
19             19 30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2               4               2                2                4    4
20             20 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1               4               1                1                4    4
21             21 21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1               3               1                1                3    3
22             22 15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2               3               2                2                3    3
23             23 15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2               3               2                2                3    3
24             24 13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4               3               4                4                3    4
25             25 19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2               3               2                2                3    3
26             26 27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1               4               1                1                4    4
27             27 26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2               5               2                2                5    5
28             28 30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2               5               2                2                5    5
29             29 15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4               5               4                4                5    5
30             30 19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6               5               6                6                5    6
31             31 15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8               5               8                8                5    8
32             32 21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2               4               2                2                4    4
   gear
1     4
2     4
3     1
4     1
5     2
6     1
7     3
8     2
9     2
10    4
11    4
12    3
13    3
14    3
15    3
16    3
17    3
18    1
19    2
20    1
21    1
22    2
23    2
24    3
25    2
26    1
27    2
28    2
29    4
30    5
31    5
32    2
>
```